# Shared drive not found when trying to run File:list

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Tried to test the Drive API v3: Files: list, got following error. I am thr owner of the drive.

---

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Shared drive not found: 1_LWGJfL7OaVHEjMKU1IZ71qIRWh1_0_S",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "driveId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Shared drive not found: 1_LWGJfL7OaVHEjMKU1IZ71qIRWh1_0_S"
 }
}
```

---